# checking available items from several arrays

Tags: javascript, database, filtering

Good day everyone.
I'm seeking for front-end solution of mostly server side task.

Lets say I have 3+ arrays - regions, ships and ports (and probably more).

The end result im expecting is - select one option, e.g. region, and all ships and ports that correspond this region remain, while the others disappear. It should be kept in mind that one ship may correspond many regions.

Unfortunately it is impossible to make ajax requests to database and check it.
All I can is make one single request at page load to get possible combinations.

Could you please give advise on how should JS filtering be done and what the incoming data be structured like for this?

Answer (score 1):

this kind of response you can send when your application first time request for it.

```
{
    "regionName":{
        "ships":[ships array]
        "porst":[ports array]
    }
}
```

then you can filter this response object by selected region value.
i.e, `regionData[selected region value]["ships"] and regionData[selected region value]["ports"]`